# Makefile. Маленький вопрос об автоматической компиляции

Tags: c++, makefile

Есть такой makefile:

```
CXX := mingw32-g++
LINK := mingw32-g++

INCLUDE := -I"../usr/include"

CXX_FLAGS := -std=c++1y -DDEBUG -g -O0 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 $(INCLUDE)

RM := rm -rf
LIBS_DIR := -L"../usr/lib/"
LIBS := -lDekaLib -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image -lSDL2_ttf 


CPP_SRCS := $(wildcard ../src/*.cpp) $(wildcard ../src/**/*.cpp)
OBJS := $(CPP_SRCS:.cpp=.o)

all: ADG.exe

%.o : %.cpp
    @echo 'Building $<'
    $(CXX) $(CXX_FLAGS) -o "$@" "$<"
    @echo 'Finished building $<'

ADG.exe: ../Debug ../Debug/resources $(OBJS)
    @echo 'Building target: $@'
    $(LINK) $(LIBS_DIR) -o "../Debug/ADG.exe" $(OBJS) $(LIBS)
    cp -r ../resources/* "../Debug/resources"
    cp -r ../usr/bin/* "../Debug"
    @echo 'Finished building target: $@'
    @echo ' '

clean:
    $(RM) $(OBJS) "../Debug"

../Debug:
    mkdir ../Debug
../Debug/resources:
    mkdir ../Debug/resources
```

Он рабочий, но он создаёт объектные файлы в папке с исходниками. Как мне сделать, чтобы объектные файлы были в той же папке, что и makefile?

Comment: 1. создаёт не файл, и даже не программа *make*, а вызываемая ею программа *mingw32-g++*. 2. то, что вы хотите сделать, во-первых, **бессмысленно**, а во-вторых, помимо того, что весьма трудно осуществимо, ещё и в случае совпадения имён файлов, просто приведёт к неработоспособности. 3. если вас по каким-то причинам не устраивает наличие об.файлов, вы можете удалить их (или переместить куда вам нужно) *после* компиляции. // самое важное слово я выделил жирным шрифтом.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваш makefile можно дополнить, обектные файлы будут создаваться в отдельном каталоге obj

```
CXX := mingw32-g++
LINK := mingw32-g++

INCLUDE := -I"../usr/include"

CXX_FLAGS := -std=c++1y -DDEBUG -g -O0 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 $(INCLUDE)

RM := rm -rf
LIBS_DIR := -L"../usr/lib/"
LIBS := -lDekaLib -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image -lSDL2_ttf 

CPP_SRCS := $(wildcard ../src/*.cpp) $(wildcard ../src/**/*.cpp)

OBJS := $(patsubst ../src/%.c,obj/%.o,$(CPP_SCRC))

all: ADG.exe

obj/%.o : %.cpp
    @echo 'Building $<'
    $(CXX) $(CXX_FLAGS) -o "$@" "$<"
    @echo 'Finished building $<'
```